# How can i have two sessions in php CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I want to have two sessions one for the admin page and the other for the users

For example you are logged in as an admin using the login form specialized for admin. While you are logged in as an admin when you go to home page you suppose to be not logged in , so you can login as a user using the website

So what i want is a session file for the admin and session file for the user

Comment: Do you mean "array" instead of "file"?

Comment: Can i create a file to save the sessions related to admin in that file and the same for user?

Comment: You could do that.

Comment: Yes that what i want to do but i don't know how? :(

Comment: No one here is going to write the code for you. Not sure if it would be the best thing to do, why save session data to a file for either type of user?

Comment: Im new to PHP and I don’t know which way is better.

Comment: Use the session array.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the session and have two "sets", one admin and one user, then make the session array multidimensional:

```
$_SESSION['admin']['username'] = "foo";
$_SESSION['admin']['token'] = 'vb$hg76%23';

$_SESSION['user']['username'] = "bar";
$_SESSION['user']['token'] = 'kb$dsj90%23';
```